# Is there a reliable way to have Cypress exit as soon as a test fails?

Tags: javascript, testing, continuous-integration, cypress

We have a large test suite running on a CI server, and there appears to be no way of telling Cypress to exit if a test fails. It always runs the entire suite.

There is some discussion [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/518), but no workable solution.

Is there a reliable way to have Cypress exit as soon as a test fails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you've mentioned, it's not officially supported yet (as of 3.6.0).

Here's my take at a hack (**without** the use of cookies and such for keeping state):

```js
// cypress/plugins/index.js

let shouldSkip = false;
module.exports = ( on ) => {
  on('task', {
    resetShouldSkipFlag () {
      shouldSkip = false;
      return null;
    },
    shouldSkip ( value ) {
      if ( value != null ) shouldSkip = value;
      return shouldSkip;
    }
  });
}
```

```js
// cypress/support/index.js

function abortEarly () {
  if ( this.currentTest.state === 'failed' ) {
    return cy.task('shouldSkip', true);
  }
  cy.task('shouldSkip').then( value => {
    if ( value ) this.skip();
  });
}

beforeEach(abortEarly);
afterEach(abortEarly);

before(() => {
  if ( Cypress.browser.isHeaded ) {
    // Reset the shouldSkip flag at the start of a run, so that it 
    //  doesn't carry over into subsequent runs.
    // Do this only for headed runs because in headless runs,
    //  the `before` hook is executed for each spec file.
    cy.task('resetShouldSkipFlag');
  }
});
```

Will skip all further tests once a failure is encountered. The output will look like:

[image]

Comment: This is a good solution, however this should definitely be supported out-of-the-box.

Comment: Agreed. Even this is an ugly hack, anyway.

Comment: Hi guys! Do you know a way to stop running even other test files? So one fail should stop the whole process of running tests

Answer (score 14):

You can also use this Cypress plugin meanwhile Cypress does not support this feature natively: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cypress-fail-fast

Add the plugin to devDependencies:

```sh
npm i --save-dev cypress-fail-fast
```

Inside cypress/plugins/index.js:

```js
module.exports = (on, config) => {
  require("cypress-fail-fast/plugin")(on, config);
  return config;
};
```

At the top of cypress/support/index.js:

```js
import "cypress-fail-fast";
```

Comment: it will not stop cypress completely, it will just abort one test file

Comment: Hi @AlexandrZavalii, that is not the expected behavior of the plugin. From [its documentation](https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-fail-fast): "If one test fails after its last retry, the rest of tests will be skipped", and there is a screenshot showing how it skips the tests in the rest of files too. If the plugin is not working that way for you, maybe you should [open an issue](https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-fail-fast/issues/25) in the plugin repository. ;)

Comment: @JavierBrea - the cypress-fail-fast is one awesome plugin. Thanks for the contributions made. We are trying to use it, but we have one blocker here. When any test fails, it stops all other suites execution which is incorrect. Only that particular suite should be failed and rest should continue. Do you have any workaround proposals? 
Ref: https://github.com/javierbrea/cypress-fail-fast/issues/100

Comment: Hi @MithunShreevatsa, the plugin should not skip other test suite files if it is configured properly. You should set "FAIL_FAST_STRATEGY" as "spec". But this only works in Cypress headless mode. In Cypress headed mode there is no way to differentiate one test suite from another (as far as I know), so all tests are skipped.  If it is not working in headless mode even when it is properly configured, then there would be a bug in the plugin, and we should continue talking about it in the related Github issue. Thanks for the feedback anyway :)